# IDs to IDs linking on menus of drawer and toolbar to nav_graph not working

Tags: java, android, uinavigationcontroller

Please, I integrated the new Navigation Controller Component, using navHostFragment. My project runs on one activity-to-many fragments. It got a drawer & toolbar. I read that it is possible to set the ids in both menus (drawer, toolbar), to same ids in nav_graph for navigation when onClick event occurs.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:id="@+id/appContainer"
tools:context=".MainFragment"
tools:openDrawer="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        android:transitionName="@string/transition_type_container" />

</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_selector"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_left_drawer" />
```

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.MainFragment"
    android:label="fragment_holder"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_holder" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/aboutFragment"
    android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.AboutFragment"
    android:label="fragment_about"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_about" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/cameraFragment"
    android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.CameraFragment"
    android:label="fragment_camera"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_camera" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/accountFragment"
    android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.AccountFragment"
    android:label="fragment_account"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_account" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/formCreateAccountFragment"
    android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.forms.FormCreateAccountFragment"
    android:label="fragment_form_create_acount"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_form_create_acount" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/formUserLoginFragment"
    android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.forms.FormUserLoginFragment"
    android:label="fragment_form_user_login"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_form_user_login" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/helpFragment"
    android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.HelpFragment"
    android:label="fragment_help"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_help" />
<activity
    android:id="@+id/cameraXActivity"
    android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.media.CameraXActivity"
    android:label="activity_camera"
    tools:layout="@layout/activity_camera" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/placeholderFragment"
    android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.ui.main.PlaceholderFragment"
    android:label="fragment_main"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
<activity
    android:id="@+id/mainActivity"
    android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.MainActivity"
    android:label="MainActivity" />
<activity
    android:id="@+id/splashActivity"
    android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.SplashActivity"
    android:label="splash_animation"
    tools:layout="@layout/splash_animation" />
<navigation android:id="@+id/nested_settings"
    app:startDestination="@id/settingsFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_settings"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/formEditAboutFragment"
        android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.forms.FormEditAboutFragment"
        android:label="fragment_form_edit_about"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_form_edit_about" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listUsersFragment"
        android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.view.ListUsersFragment"
        android:label="fragment_list_users"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list_users" />
</navigation>
<navigation android:id="@+id/nested_tips"
    app:startDestination="@id/searchFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/searchFragment"
        android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.SearchFragment"
        android:label="fragment_search"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/tipsFragment"
        android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.TipsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_tips"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_tips" />
</navigation>
<navigation android:id="@+id/nested_tasks"
    app:startDestination="@id/tasksFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/tasksFragment"
        android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.TasksFragment"
        android:label="fragment_tasks"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_tasks" />
</navigation>
<navigation android:id="@+id/nested_notifications"
    app:startDestination="@id/notificationsFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/notificationsFragment"
        android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.NotificationsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_notifications"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notifications" />
</navigation>
<navigation android:id="@+id/nested_report"
    app:startDestination="@id/reportFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/reportFragment"
        android:name="com.emexrevolarter.worksmart.ReportFragment"
        android:label="fragment_report"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_report" />
</navigation>
```

**menu_left_drawer.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:id="@+id/leftDrawer"
tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<group
    android:id="@+id/group1"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/aboutFragment"
        android:title="@string/drawer_about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_info_24"
        android:iconTint="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <item android:title="@string/drawer_label">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/helpFragment"
                android:title="@string/drawer_help"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_help_24"
                android:iconTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </menu>

    </item>
</group>
```

**main_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/notificationsFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_notifications_24"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:visible="false"
    android:title="Notification">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/searchFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:visible="false"
    android:title="Search">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/accountFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock_open_24"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="Account">
</item>
```

Everything works as per navigation if I use the below:

```
    subText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // action_global_aboutFragment
            NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(v);
            navController.navigate(R.id.nested_settings);
        }
    });
```

**More Info:**

```
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
```

**Implementation:**

```
// Java language implementation
def nav_version = "2.3.3"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```

I need a solution to this, as regards IDs to IDs linking. I love the concept. Who got this working on Android Java?

Comment: The `nav_graph.xml` you posted only has `id/aboutFragment` and `id/helpFragment`, but your menu has many other IDs. Are those also present in your graph? Please include your entire graph.

Comment: nav_graph been edited to include in entire graph

Comment: Is there a reason you have nested graphs with just a single destination within them?

Comment: Yes I do. They are like separate services within the app. They will have 3 or more fragments under them. All the nested links are working fine, when I use onClickListener

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Listeners are needed for both Drawer & Toolbar

```
    // setup click listeners for Drawer & Toolbar
    drawerView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            int id = menuItem.getItemId();
            if(id == R.id.accountFragment) {
                // add your code here
            } else {
                NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(menuItem, navController);
            }
            drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
            // drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
    });

    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle Menu item selection
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.aboutFragment:
                    // add your code here
                    return true;
                default:
                    // default function;
                    NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController);
                    return true;
            }
            // return false;
        }
    });
```

Thank you.